# Universal App: Getting Table View To Fill Whole Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two table views, both without table view controllers, I have a view controller that's taking care of both of them.

The problem is that I'm getting weird scalings of the tables on different devices. It seems to be almost perfect on the iPhone 4 simulator. The table looks almost ridiculous on any iPad simulator.

My Table Views View settings look like this:

[image: settings]

> scale to fill

I tried changing the launch images to see if that would have any impact on scaling/zooming/etc, but that didn't really seem to change anything.

- How Can I Get My Table Views To Automatically Fill The Whole Screen On A Universal App?

edit:

alignment constraints are disabled:

[image: constraints]

Comment: you are using autolayout?

Comment: I think your question's answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920798/xcode-ios-autoresize-to-fill-a-view-explicit-frame-size-is-essential

Comment: @AshishKakkad yes autolayout is on.

Comment: @ozgur how can I get that to work with my TableView?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the autolayout give constaints to table view as leading, trailing, top & bottom. It will change  its size as per device.

Comment: the leading, trailing, top & bottom constraints are greyed-out?!

Comment: Can you please try by clearing all the constraints of the view & then add new constraints. Remember while adding constraint uncheck the constraints to margin button

Comment: I don't have any constraints at the moment, but they seem to be all disabled.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of how you are setting the constraints if possible

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot of the disabled constraints I was trying to add

Comment: Hope it will work, Their is one more way to add constraint, select the tableView from sidemenu hierarchy from storyboard, press Ctrl & drag from tableview to it's super view. then one popup will appear from their You select leading , trailing , top & bottom contraints

Comment: Worked! Excellent, thanks so much. One problem: I don't think it's counting my nav bar - so I have a bunch of things hidden behind the nav bar - any tips?

Comment: Yes...While adding constraint to viewcontroller first you select the device screen size as 3.5 inch & add topbar as translusent navigation bar. & then only you put your objects in the view & set the constraints so that nothing is hidden under navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the frame of the table view to occupy the whole screen

```
UITableView tableView = [[UITableView alloc]  initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```